# Mapping function to list/array in haskell?

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to make Conway's Game of Life in Haskell. I am very new to Haskell and functional programming in general, and having trouble making an array in haskell to represent the game board.

I am trying to initiate a random array to begin the game. To do that I create a function randomBoard which returns '*' or ' ' to represent a space on the game board.

I want to be able to create the game board array with this function. I havent been able to succesfully instantiate an array yet. I am hoping there is a way i can declare an array of say size 100 and use my random function to set each element.

```
import System.Random
import Data.Array
import Data.List

randomBoard = 
   do 
   f1 <- randomIO :: IO Int
   if(f1 `mod` 2) == 0
     then return  '*'
     else return  ' '

boardArray :: Array Int Char
boardArray = listArray (0, 100) . map randomBoard $ 100 (0,100)
```

This obviously doesnt work or even compile. I am sure there are a couple things wrong with it, as I am not sure really how to even work with IO in haskell and produce this outcome. Any guidance is much appreciated...

Comment: I made Game of Life as one of my first projects in Haskell. I would advise you to forget about `Data.Array` and just use a nested `[[Bool]]` for the game board. `Data.Array` is much more efficient, but a nested list is much easier to use especially for beginners. Additionally it is easier to use a `Bool` as the state type rather than a `Char`, as a `Bool` naturally maps to the on/off nature of the cell state.

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import Data.Array
import Data.List

randomBoard :: IO Char
randomBoard =
   do
   f1 <- randomIO :: IO Int
   if(f1 `mod` 2) == 0
     then return  '*'
     else return  ' '

boardArray :: IO (Array Int Char)
boardArray = listArray (0, 99) <$> replicateM 100 randomBoard
```

Here's what I changed:

1. I added the type signature `randomBoard :: IO Char` for clarity. (The code would still work without it, as Haskell correctly infers this type if you don't supply it.)
2. I changed the type of `boardArray` to use `IO`. Anything that uses `IO`, no matter how indirectly, need to be in `IO` itself.
3. I changed `listArray (0, 100)` to `listArray (0, 99)`, as the former would actually be 101 elements.
4. `map randomBoard $ 100 (0,100)` isn't right at all. To get a list of several of the same thing, you'd usually use `replicate`, but since the thing you care about here is in the `IO` monad, you use `replicateM` instead. `replicateM 100 randomBoard` gives an `IO [Char]` with 100 random elements of either `'*'` or `' '`.
5. I added an import of `Control.Monad`, which is needed to use `replicateM`.
6. I use `<$>` in `boardArray`. Since you want to call `listArray` with a `[Char]` and get an `Array Int Char`, but `replicateM 100 randomBoard` is an `IO [Char]`, you can't just apply the argument directly. Using `<$>` (which is also called `fmap`) applies it "inside" of `IO`, giving you back an `IO (Array Int Char)`.

Comment: This is awesome and makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. Follow up question, what is the best way to print boardArray to screen? Previously i was using putStr.

Comment: @Anon. For debugging, you could just `print` it and get something that looks like `array (0,99) [(0,' '),(1,' '),(2,'*'),...,(98,'*'),(99,'*')]`. If you want something prettier, then a custom function with `putStr` probably is your best bet.

Comment: @Anon. The _best_ way is probably to define your own custom function `showBoard :: Array Int Char -> String` which should iterate over the array and convert it to a `String`; this allows you to format it nicely as well. Then you can print that with `putStrLN`.