# Function that takes an array of chars and returns a concatenated string. Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Ugh... Struggling with haskell. Trying to implement Conway's GOL and create a random game board. Here is where I am at.

I have a function to randomize each square in an array, and a function to create an array of characters using the randomization function to represent my game board.

I am trying to now create a function: showBoard, which iterates through the array and concatenates each char to a string which I can print out in my main.

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array
import Data.List

randomBoard = do
    f1 <- randomIO :: IO Int
    if(f1 `mod` 2) == 0
        then return  '*'
        else return  ' '

boardArray :: IO (Array Int Char)
boardArray = listArray (0, 99) <$> replicateM 100 randomBoard


showBoard :: IO (Array Int Char) -> Int -> String -> String
showBoard arr i str = do
    if i > 0
       then showBoard arr (i-1) (str ++ (arr ! i))
       else return str

main :: IO ()
main = 
let board = showBoard boardArray 100 ""
    in
        do
            putStr board
```

I have spent an hour trying to tweak this out and keep getting type issues. I cant even get this board to print x.x please help.

Comment: It looks like you're the same person as [Anon.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9319699/anon) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56318231/7509065). You may want to [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

1. It's not possible to write a function that takes an `IO` of something and uses it to return something that isn't in `IO`. Change `showBoard` to take an `Array Int Char` without the `IO` wrapper, and remove `do` and `return` from it.
2. Since your array is zero-based, change `arr ! i` to `arr ! (i - 1)`.
3. `arr` contains `Char`s, not `String`s, so use `[]` instead of `()` around the indexing of it to make it into a `String`.
4. Since we made `showBoard` take a value without `IO`, use `<-` in `main` to get at the inner value we need.

Here's the result of all of those changes:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array
import Data.List

randomBoard = do
    f1 <- randomIO :: IO Int
    if(f1 `mod` 2) == 0
        then return  '*'
        else return  ' '

boardArray :: IO (Array Int Char)
boardArray = listArray (0, 99) <$> replicateM 100 randomBoard


showBoard :: Array Int Char -> Int -> String -> String
showBoard arr i str =
    if i > 0
       then showBoard arr (i-1) (str ++ [arr ! (i - 1)])
       else str

main :: IO ()
main = do
    randomArray <- boardArray
    let board = showBoard randomArray 100 ""
    putStr board
```

As an aside, the way `showBoard` is implemented, although it works, is particularly inefficient. You should avoid doing things that look like `x ++ [y]` recursively, as it's quadratically slow. Also, it looks like your function prints the elements starting at the end and going down to 0, rather than starting at 0 and going up to the end. Here's a new version of it that fixes both of those things at once:

```
showBoard :: Array Int Char -> Int -> String -> String
showBoard arr i str =
    if i > 0
       then showBoard arr (i-1) ((arr ! (i - 1)) : str)
       else str
```

Using `:` where possible is much more efficient than always using `++`.

You can simplify even further by not having `showBoard` at all, and using [`elems`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:elems) (from `Data.Array`) instead:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    randomArray <- boardArray
    let board = elems randomArray
    putStr board
```

Comment: Wow thanks! This is starting to make sense. Thanks for the advice on the efficiency as well. It works perfectly :)